# probability of correctly ranking stream of random numbers

Tags: probability, game-theory

This is a problem I came up with after seeing a similar game on tiktok.

Suppose you are given a stream of k numbers where each number is sampled from a uniform distribution between 0 and 1. Before you can see the next number in the stream, you have to guess where the current number will rank (1st to kth place) in the final ordered list of all k generated random numbers. What is the probability, in terms of k, of generating a correct ordering?

I'm pretty sure if k=2, the probability is 0.75. Beyond that I have no idea how to continue. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you get 0.75 for k = 2 ? That can't be correct.

Comment: I'm quite sure this has been asked a few weeks ago

Comment: What algorithm are you using for generating the ranking? Or is the question how good the optimal algorithm can be?

Comment: @trueblueanil here's how I solved for k=2:
instead of having it generate random numbers between 0 and 1, I have it generate random integers between 1 and N (without repetition), and then take the limit as N -> infinity.


let i1 be the first random integer, and i2 be the second. 


if i1>N/2, we rank it 2nd and if i1<N/2, we rank it first. 


WLOG, assume i1>N/2 (the other case mirrors exactly)


because i1 is sampled from a uniform distribution, p(i1 = x) = 1/(N/2)


i2 is also sampled from a uniform distribution, so p(win) = p(i2<i1) = (i1 - 1)/(N-1)
By my math, this is 0.75

Comment: @leonbloy I'll look for that post! If you happen to find it, please let me know

Comment: @PhoemueX My question was how well the optimal algorithm would be, but here's my idea for an algorithm that seems optimal to me (Obviously I haven't proven it): Let *i* be the number you're trying to rank. let *a* and *b* be the nearest numbers already ranked such that *a*<*i*<*b* (if no such numbers exist, fill in 0 as *a* or 1 as *b* as needed) and let *A* and *B* be the ranks of *a* and *b* respectively. *i*'s rank will be *A* + ceiling([(*i*-*a*)/(*b*-*a*)]x(*B*-*A*))

Comment: @PhoemueX Also forgot to add if *A* - *B* = 0 obviously you've lost. Also, after thinking about it I think this strategy could be proven to be optimal pretty straightforwardly with induction.